# Adding second json object(s) causes undefined error in reactjs web app

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api

My previous question was asking how to map through a json object I have using json-server and a small reactjs web app that I'm currently working on. When one object is in mockData everything works just fine but when I add a second object such as this:

```
{
  "mockData": [
    {
    "grapevine": [
      { 
        "entity": "67.6.201.77", 
        "category": "scan", 
        "source": "emotet_tracker",
        "rscore": 42 
      },
      { 
        "entity": "67.6.201.77", 
        "category": "popular", 
        "source": "vinter",
        "rscore": 69 
      },
      { 
        "entity": "67.6.201.77", 
        "category": "spam", 
        "source": "uceprotect",
        "rscore": 48 
      },
      { 
        "entity": "67.6.201.77", 
        "category": "c2", 
        "source": "c2_validator",
        "rscore": 41 
      },
      { 
        "entity": "67.6.201.77", 
        "category": "scan", 
        "source": "greenleaf",
        "rscore": 37 
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "shodan": [
      { 
        "port": 22, 
        "protocol": "TCP", 
        "service": "SSH",
        "banner": "SSH-2.0-libssh-0.2" 
      },
      { 
        "port": 22, 
        "protocol": "TCP", 
        "service": "SSH",
        "banner": "SSH-2.0-libssh-0.2" 
      },
      { 
        "port": 23, 
        "protocol": "TCP", 
        "service": "telnet",
        "banner": "None" 
      },
      { 
        "port": 80, 
        "protocol": "TCP", 
        "service": "HTTP",
        "banner": "GoAhead-Webs" 
      }
    ]
   }
  ]
}
```

I get an *TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined* pointing at this code:

```
  42 | </tr>
  43 | </thead>
  44 | <tbody>
> 45 | {this.state.gvEntries.map(grapevine => (
  46 |   <tr>
  47 |       <td>{grapevine.entity}</td>
  48 |       <td>{grapevine.category}</td>

  13 | componentDidMount() {
  14 | fetch("http://localhost:3000/mockData/")
  15 |   .then(grapevine => grapevine.json())
> 16 |   .then(data => this.setState({ gvEntries: data.grapevine }));
  17 | }
  18 | 
  19 | render() {
```

If I add that second object, aka "shodan" am I no longer mapping mockData properly? I'm trying to pass multiple json objects into different cards/panels on the dashboard. Thanks!

Comment: who is `data.grapevine` or where is the mock for the `grapevine` data??

Comment: You have to set the initial state in the constructor. Otherwise, as `fetch` is async, until `setState` is called `this.state.gvEntries` will be undefined.

Comment: @kenry I'm sorry I don't understand your question (bit new to react). If your asking where it's hosted I have it running as a mock api locally json-server

Comment: constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      gvEntries: [],
    };
  }

Comment: as you can see above I have it set in my constructor. Is this what ya'll mean?

Answer (score 0):

i think you should make the following change:
componentDidMount() {

```
 14 | fetch("http://localhost:3000/mockData/")
  15 |   .then(grapevine => grapevine.json())
> 16 |   .then(data => this.setState({ gvEntries: [data.grapevine] }));
  17 | }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider the fact that `this.state.gvEntries` might not have been initialized when the `render()` method is called.

You should make a check in the beginning of the `render` method to check if it exists or (best pratice), to define the state in the constructor of the componenet.

```
construcotr(props) {
  super(props);  
  this.state = { gvEntries: [] };
}
```

**edit**

By looking at the structure of the json it should be `this.setState({ gvEntries: data.mockData[0].grapevine })`

Comment: I did set it in constructor:                                                               
 constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      gvEntries: [],
    };
  }

Comment: If `data` of the last `then()` is the json you show the edit above should be correct

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work and I get this error Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: What is the output if you make a console log of the json `.then(data => console.log(data));`?

Comment: yes, that's beacause of `mockData[0]`, but don't do the `setState` and just log the result so we can see if what you get is the actual json as you expect it to be

Comment: Array(2)
0
:
{grapevine: Array(5)}
1
:
{shodan: Array(4)}
length
:
2
__proto__
:
Array(0)

Comment: That's it, so you should do `this.setState({ gvEntries: data[0].grapevine })`

Comment: I could kiss you, thank you so much that worked! I appreciate you hanging in there with me.